# AVFrame to OpenCV: Mat vs GpuMat

Tags: opencv, gpu, mat, libav

I'm working with [this](http://hasanaga.info/tag/ffmpeg-avframe-to-opencv-mat/) code, line 85. I'm struggling with an issue when initialising a GpuMat in OpenCV. My CUDA environment is working 100% fine, but when I try to execute these two lines of code:

```
cv::cuda::GpuMat img(pFrame->height,pFrame->width,CV_8UC3, pFrameRGB->data[0]);
cv::Mat imgC(pFrame->height,pFrame->width,CV_8UC3, pFrameRGB->data[0]);
```

only the Mat initialization is working. When I try to display the GpuMat using imshow, the program crashes with the following error:

```
opengl.cpp:226: error: (-217:Gpu API call) invalid argument in function 'copyFrom'
```

pFrameRGB is a 4K size AVFrame with `AV_PIX_FMT_BGR24` pixel format.

Do someone know how to deal with this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: Does it output some kind of a stack trace?

Comment: You're supposed to call `upload` to load cpu memory to gpu memory so after loading the image into an ordinary `Mat` you then call `img.upload(other_Mat)` for instance. So you could call `img.upload(imgC)` but you can't construct a GpuMat and pass a pointer to your data like this AFAIK

Comment: @Selaron the only error I can see is the one I showed unfortunately

Comment: @EdChum yes, that works, but I'm trying to load the AVFrame data directly into the GpuMat without downloading it on the CPU

Comment: You'd have to do a `cudaMalloc` and pass a `void**` as the data member, not an ordinary pointer: http://answers.opencv.org/question/72196/c-pointer-to-gpumat/ but you'd still have to copy this memory to the cuda memory at some point so I'm not sure you're saving anything

Comment: Also your error is pointing a problem in openGL? This maybe the problem in transferring ownership

Comment: @EdChum ok I'm trying to understand...I defined `LoadFrameData` and did a `cudaMalloc`, then I defined the GpuMat. But then, I have to fill `LoadFrameData` with my `pFrameRGB->data[0]`. This leads to a black image, though. 
Moreover, I think the problem with openGL is just due to the fact that I am using a `cv::WINDOW_OPENGL` in the `imshow`, but that is not a problem usually for me

Comment: I don't deal with OpenGL so I can't comment on why this maybe the case. I would focus on just getting it to work first and foremost so if calling `upload` and passing a cpu allocated `Mat` then use this for now. It maybe worth posting a question on http://answers.opencv.org/questions/ where you should get more specific help

Comment: As of now it works correctly when passing the Mat's data to the GpuMat via upload, but I'm trying to avoid that in order to increase performance